# JavaScript and leaking global variables

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, if you do:

```
var myvar = 5;
```

Then it will be local to that file, however if you accidentally forget `var` and just do:

```
myvar = 5;
```

Then it becomes global.

Is there any good solution to fixing this, it seems to me that the default should have been that it is local, and you should do something like `global myvar = 5` in order to get a global.

There is `"use strict";` that I discovered to warn you but I was hoping for a more elegant solution and thought it must exist?

Comment: You should always use `var` anyways.

Comment: @PaulPRO — Of course, but the question is about the times that you *accidentally forget*

Comment: "local to that file" should be "local to that function" (scope in JavaScript is function-based, not file-based). As to solutions: what's wrong with `"use strict"`? It has been designed as a solution for this very problem, it turns undeclared variables into errors.

Comment: @Quentin If you're in a habit of always using it you'll never accidentally forget

Comment: You could use [coffeescript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/). It's a really neat language that keeps the power and general feel of javascript while fixing some language design errors like variable scoping, and it compiles to javascript.

Comment: @PaulPRO — Practise doesn't really make perfect, it just gets you closer. Mistakes still happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Then it will be local to that file

No, it will be local to that **function**

> however if you accidentally forget "var"…
>   Is there any good solution to fixing this

[JS Lint](http://jslint.com/) will shout at you for using globals and JS now supports [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode) (although not all browsers have caught up with it).

> There is "use strict"; that I discovered to warn you but I was hoping for a more elegant solution

Strict mode *is* elegant.

Comment: The problem is that you have to put "use strict"; at the top of every single JS file, when developing on Node.js and in the Browser and have 30+ JS files, it is easy to forget to put the use strict at the top of the file, then stop being warned. If there was a way to set use strict globally that would be great.